# Combine SQL queries if a column is NULL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following VBA code:

```
Set cRec = g_cDataBase.SqlQuery("SELECT sEmployeeName, lArchitectId FROM tblBuilders WHERE Id = " & lDbId)

If cRec.RecordCount = 0 Then
    Exit Function
End If

If IsNull(cRec("sEmployeeName")) Then
    
    Set cRec = g_cDataBase.SqlQuery("SELECT sEmployeeName FROM tblArchitects WHERE Id = " & cRec("lArchitectId"))
    
    If cRec.RecordCount = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    
End If
```

Can i combine the queries to a single query? When an sEmployeeName is null in the tblBuilders table it needs to give the sEmployeeName from the tblArchitects table based on the first query lArchitectId.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @marc_s: In general, yes, but there can be nothing to inject here.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT b.sEmployeeName, b.lArchitectId, a.sEmployeeName
FROM tblBuilders as b LEFT JOIN
     tblArchitects as a
     ON a.id = b.lArchitectId
WHERE b.Id = " & lDbId;
```

EDIT:

If you want one architect, then use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT b.sEmployeeName, b.lArchitectId,
       NZ(b.sEmployeeName,
          (SELECT TOP (1) a.sEmployeeName
           FROM tblArchitects as a
           WHERE a.id = b.lArchitectId
          )
         ) as imputed_employeename
FROM tblBuilders as b          
WHERE b.Id = " & lDbId;
```

Note:  Without an `ORDER BY` in the subquery this returns an *arbitrary* name.  If you have a definition of "first" use that in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a conditional `IIF` + `IS NULL` logic between both employee name columns. Then, save below SQL as a stored query and pass parameters in VBA via [QueryDefs parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-parameters-property-dao)

#### **SQL**

```sql
PARAMETERS idparam LONG;
SELECT IIF(b.sEmployeeName IS NULL,
           a.sEmployeeName,
           b.sEmployeeName) AS notnullEmployeeName 
FROM tblBuilders b
LEFT JOIN tblArchitects a
  ON b.Id = a.lArchitectId
WHERE b.Id = idparam
```

If all rows of `tblBuilders` can potentially be missing compared to  `tblArchitects` by same corresponding `Id`, then run MS Access equivalent of full join:

**Full Join Query**

```sql
SELECT b.Id, b.sEmployeeName AS bldsEmployeeName
     , a.lArchitectId, a.sEmployeeName AS archsEmployeeName
FROM tblBuilders b
LEFT JOIN tblArchitects a
   ON b.Id = a.lArchitectId

UNION

SELECT b.Id, b.sEmployeeName AS bldsEmployeeName
     , a.lArchitectId, a.sEmployeeName AS archsEmployeeName
FROM tblBuilders b
RIGHT JOIN tblArchitects a
   ON b.Id = a.lArchitectId
```

**Final Query**

```sql
PARAMETERS idparam LONG;
SELECT IIF(bldsEmployeeName IS NULL,
           archsEmployeeName,
           bldsEmployeeName) AS notnullEmployeeName 
FROM myfulljoinquery
WHERE Id = idparam
   OR lArchitectId = idparam
```

#### **VBA**

```vb
Dim cRec As Recordset
Dim qdef As QueryDef

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("myFinalSavedQuery")

' BIND PARAMS
qdef!idparam = lDbId

' CREATE RECORDSET
Set cRec = qdef.OpenRecordset()

' ... DO STUFF ON cRec ...

cRec.close()
Set qdef = Nothing: Set cRec = Nothing
```